# Google chrome not opening in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Google Chrome does not run. I have reinstalled it many times and also restarted my computer, but it still does not run. All it does is just showing the icon and when you click it it will not open.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: please run `whereis google-chrome-stable` what does it return.

Comment: @George `google-chrome-stable: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` I have same issue

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue. By running `google-chrome` from terminal, I found that it needed a new version of NSS:

```
$ google-chrome

[6999:7036:1113/200616.549496:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So I installed `libnss3`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3
```

and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

**It's worked**

I uninstalled it by `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome` and then `rm ~/.config/google-chrome -rf` and then installing it back. First, I tried to install it via Google's official website and then downloading `.deb` file there, but after downloading the installer application of Ubuntu 16.04 stuck, even it isn't working now. Then, I tried to install it via terminal by writing

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Some applications would install OK, and when clicking, they would "Open", or at least they would shake like they were opening, but in effect nothing happened.

It turned out to be because I have a Graphics card, and the system mistakenly thought I had two monitors so the applications were opening on this phantom monitor.

If this is the case for you, go to `System Settings > Displays` and if there is an extra display, disable it.

I also went on to install the nvidia driver which helped with other problems

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue in which when I typed command google-chrome on terminal it showed me error of SingletonLock File in `/.config/google-chrome/` directory. I deleted that file and then it worked.

To identify the type of error you are facing try to open the program using command line and then analyse error returned back from command-line.

Answer (score 0):

you may try Chromuim which is more stable and better for video watching by the way

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but for me the below worked in terminal.

```
sed -i -e 's@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox@g' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Comment: Hi, might want to explain what that command does.