# Chrome not opening in lubuntu 16.10

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome

#### Story

I've checked various older guides on how to install Google Chrome until I finally got it working, but once I finally got it installed (after much trouble manually installing some missing packages) it didn't open, not even once.

#### Computer

- HP Notebook, pretty old.
- 2 GB RAM
- AMD CPU Dual Core 1700 MHz
- Running LUbuntu 16.10 64-bit

#### Chrome Installation

I downloaded the file from the official Google page for Ubuntu 64-bit, then I installed it through GDebi, while having to install missing packages manually.

#### Problem

Chrome doesn't open, never has since installed.

#### Diagnosis

```
$ google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 55: /opt/google/chrome/chrome: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 55: /opt/google/chrome/chrome: Success
```

And nothing happens (same for google-chrome-stable).

```
$ whereis google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

Installing the file:

```
$ sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'google-chrome-stable:amd64' instead of './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-chrome-stable:amd64
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/46,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 180 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable:amd64.
(Reading database ... 194730 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_55.0.2883.87-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable:amd64 (55.0.2883.87-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable:amd64 (55.0.2883.87-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
```

Suggestions from David Foerster

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/google-chrome
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

And

```
$ file /opt/google/chrome/chrome
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=77d30c39976a4947b23b12abb107e28f66637823, stripped
```

I saw another thread ([Google chrome not opening in ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864408/google-chrome-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)) that spoke about the same thing (only in 16.04), but it has been dead for the last 2 days...

Comment: Are you running athe 32-bit version of Google Chrome on 64-bit Lubuntu?

Comment: How did you install it? Did you download it from Google or from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable?

Comment: Added the information you asked about to the post.

Comment: What's the output of `readlink -f /usr/bin/google-chrome` and `file /opt/google/chrome/chrome`? What happens when you run `google-chrome-stable`?

Comment: 'google-chrome-stable' outputs the same as 'google-chrome', added the rest of the outputs to the post.

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling Google Chrome `sudo apt remove --purge google-chrome-stable`. When Google Chrome has been'uninstalled, download a new Google Chrome .deb file. The next step is to move the newly downloaded `.deb` file into your home directory. Now open up a terminal and type `sudo apt install ./[NAME-OF-THE-DEB-FILE]`.

Comment: Couldn't fix it; looked through the install log:

Comment: and found this:

Note, selecting 'google-chrome-stable:amd64' instead of './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'

PS: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter without using shift....