# Google Chrome browser doesn't open in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, intel-graphics, integrated

Google Chrome browser doesn't open in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It doesn't open when I clicked on the icon. I tried to open in other ways as well. It doesn't open even when I typed `google-chrome` in the terminal, command line interface. I'm using Intel Pentium G4560 CPU which has integrated factory graphics. I don't use any other Graphics card on my PC. When I type `google-chrome` only without trying to open with clicking on its icon it shows nothing, but when I type `google-chrome` after trying to open the browser by clicking on its icon it shows the following message on terminal:

```
[7136:7170:0801/232639.382646:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

So I don't know if this problem is related to graphics or some other problem. I also had similar problem with Chromium and Opera browsers. Vivaldi opens, but I cannot open new window with Vivaldi. I have HTML5 and other incompatibilities with Mozilla Firefox browser even if it does open.

This is my `lspci` command's output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 590f (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5902 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
```

Important note: I don't know how safe it is to share outputs of some commands in command line interface, terminal. Please inform me if I share anything that makes me vulnurable to the security attacks.

Edit: I tried to uninstall and then install Google Chrome browser, but it didn't work. I uninstalled it by `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome` and then `rm ~/.config/google-chrome -rf` and then installing it back. First, I tried to install it via Google's official website and then downloading .deb file there, but after downloading the installer application of Ubuntu 16.04 stuck, even it isn't working now. Then, I tried to install it via terminal by writing

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

But, still it doesn't work. The browser doesn't open.
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the entire error messages/warnings that show up when running it from terminal.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall it?

Comment: @BONEPIEBONEPIE No, I will try it.

Comment: Ok, cool, tell me if it works or not. :)

Comment: @BONEPIEBONEPIE Sorry, but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: [This worked instantly!!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864408/google-chrome-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/976041#976041) sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned off the "Built-in Display" in System Settings -> Displays menu. The problematic browsers are working now. I learned it when I took the screenshot, because it showed double screen on the screenshot since "Built-in Display" was on before.

Edit on 28 Sep 2017: I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after trying many different OSes. Now I faced the same problem but this time I solved it with a different approach, in System Settings -> Display menu I ticked on "Mirror Displays". All other options did not work for me this time. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have only one monitor? Otherwise, how is mirroring displays a viable solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Chromium and Chrome. Both browsers did not start until I disabled "built-in" display.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.