# Chrome is not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I haven't remember that what I did on my system that cause the chrome browser not working. All the things were going fine but now when I click the chrome browser icon then it is not opening. I have re-installed it but still have the same problem.

I have gone through below practices to resolve this issue:

To reset chrome back to fresh install

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

and

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

When I have tried it to open through terminal using command: google-chrome it returns me with below mentioned error:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[8831:8831:0228/065113.899190:ERROR:sync_control_vsync_provider.cc (62)] glXGetSyncValuesOML should not return TRUE with a media stream counter of 0.
```

It works when I turn off the "Built-in Display" in System Settings -> Displays menu.

Can anybody please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I just have revert the settings under the Software & Updates then Updated system software to go through Software Updater. I also restore the settings to use this command:  dconf reset -f /

But after all that Chrome is still not working.

Comment: The question explaination helped me. `google-chrome --disable-gpu` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hayee everyone, its working now!

I just made some settings under the Setting >> Display. First I checked the mirror option and applied and then again uncheck the mirror option and select the Built-in-Display next to the Launcher Placement.

I have found this trick here on the same forum: [Google Chrome browser doesn't open in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942031/google-chrome-browser-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Thanks to all of you!